# Is it possible to generate random numbers in MS Access that do not change everytime a query is run?

Tags: ms-access-2007, random-access

I am trying to pull a random set of 200 records from my Microsoft Access database.  I created a query and used the rnd() function in a new field to generate a random number for each record.  I then sorted the random number field and retrieved the top 200 articles.  My problem is that every time I run the query, I get different random numbers.  I know that in other programs, you can set a user-defined value for the seed, and this problem will be fixed, however I do not know how to set the seed value myself in MS Access.  Is this possible to do?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try reading the Access help for the Rnd() function? The function has a single argument, and the help file defines what the seed does:

```
   If number is            Rnd generates 
   Less than zero          The same number every time, using number as the seed. 
   Greater than zero       The next random number in the sequence. 
   Equal to zero           The most recently generated number. 
   Not supplied            The next random number in the sequence.
```

So, you want to pass a negative number that is the same for each row each time you run the query. An Autonumber PK would be an ideal candidate for that, since it will be unique -- just use `Rnd(-MyPK)`.

The only problem would be if you are using random Autonumbers, in which case some of the numbers would be negative already, so you'd have a problem there. I don't have a good solution to that that would avoid collisions (i.e., two rows producing the same value because they have the same absolute value) and that wouldn't lead to an overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Simply square the autonumber before taking the negative to remove the "already negative" problem?